# vue js post запрос fetch

Tags: vue.js

Такая проблема, при клике на кнопку должен передаваться параметр value на сервер
но при отправки в ответ присылает "response":false,"errors":"The value field is required.""
Вот код:

```
<td class="flex">
    <input type="text" name="text" v-model="name" class="form-control finance-width">
    <button class="button-add mini-button form-control" v-on:click="addIncomes()">Add</button>
</td>
data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            getIncomes: [],
            outcome: {},
            purchase: {}
        }
    },

async addIncomes() {
            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('name', this.name);

            const responseIncomes = await fetch('https://lys.open-k.com/realty/income?realty_id=' + this.$parent.realtyId, {
                method: "POST",
                body: fd
            })
            if (responseIncomes.status !== 200) {
                console.error('Income | error')
            }

            const incomeResponse = await responseIncomes.json()
            this.getIncomes.push(incomeResponse)

            this.name = ''
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

Разве вы не передаёте **name** вместо **value**?

> The value field is required

говорит о том, что бэк ждёт обязательный проп **value**.